# Can a random variable symmetric about zero be uniquely defined by the difference of two other iid random variables with mean zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $Y$ be a random variable symmetric about $0$ with characteristic function $\phi_Y(t)$.

If $Y=X_j-X_i$, with $X_i,X_j \overset{iid}{\sim} X$, with characteristic function $\phi_X(t)$.

Then $\phi_Y(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_{-X}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_{X}(-t)=\phi_X(t)\overline{\phi_X(t)}$.

With the constraint $E[X]=0$, i.e., $i^{-1}\phi_X^\prime(0)=0$, is $\phi_X(t)$ unique?

For example, if $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$, is $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ unique?

Comment: If $X$ is asymmetric then $Z=-X$ gives another solution.

Comment: Thanks! That's a sharp observation. And if $X$ is symmetric then $\phi_X(t)=\phi_{-X}(t)=[\phi_Y(t)]^\frac{1}{2}$ is unique. Are there many mean-zero asymmetric $X$s that lead to the same $Y$, or is it unique up to your $-X, X$ case?

Comment: In Volume 2 of Feller's book there is an example of distinct characteristic functions $\phi, \psi$ such that $\phi^{2}(t)=\psi^{2}(t)$ for all $t$. Note that  $|\phi^{2}(t)|=|\psi^{2}(t)|$ so you have counter-example.